# Android: InfoWindowAdapter not showing image

Tags: android, google-maps, android-volley, infowindow, image-loading

I am working on maps in my application. In which i used InfoWindowAdapter. I am having image view in that. But on opening the info window image is not display.

The xml of infoWindow is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_infoWindow"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the Activity code is as follow:

```
public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public LatLng MOUNTAIN_VIEW;
    int METERS = 20000;
    final private int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_FOR_ACCESS_LOCATION = 123;

    List<MarkerOptions> markerOptionsList;
    ArrayList<ModelLocation> modelLocation;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setElevation(2);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Location");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        if (checkPermission()) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(MOUNTAIN_VIEW)
            .zoom(17)                   
            .bearing(360)                
            .tilt(45)                  
            .build();                 
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                final LatLng latLng = cameraPosition.target;

                final Location location = new Location("Camera_Location");
                location.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
                location.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);

                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LocationActivity.this, R.style.ProgressBarTansparent);
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressbar_layout);

                String url = "My URL To Get Data";
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("Key","Value");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                final JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArrayUserList = response.getJSONArray("ABC");
                            modelLocation = new ArrayList<>();

                            int size = jsonArrayUserList.length();
                            if (size > 0) {
                                for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayUserList.getJSONObject(count);

                                    int userID = jsonObject.getInt("userID");
                                    String Name = jsonObject.getString("address");
                                    String address = jsonObject.getString("ADD");
                                    float latitude = Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.getString("latitude"));
                                    float longitude = Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.getString("longitude"));
                                    String image = jsonObject.getString("image");


                                    ModelLocation modelLocation1 = new ModelLocation(userID, Name, address, latitude, longitude, image);
                                    modelLocation.add(modelLocation1);
                                }

                                Location target = new Location("target");

                                for (ModelLocation modelLocation1 : modelLocation) {
                                    target.setLatitude(modelLocation1.latitude);
                                    target.setLongitude(modelLocation1.longitude);
                                    LatLng point = new LatLng(modelLocation1.latitude, modelLocation1.longitude);

                                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().title(modelLocation1.Name).snippet(modelLocation1.address).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin)).anchor(0.0f, 1.0f).position(point);
                                    if (location.distanceTo(target) < METERS) {
                                        if (isMarkerOnArray(markerOptionsList, markerOptions)) {
                                        } else {
                                        markerOptionsList.add(markerOptions);
                                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                            dropic_pinEffect(marker);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                Volley.newRequestQueue(LocationActivity.this).add(postRequest);
            }
        });

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
                LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                for (int count = 0; count < modelLocation.size(); count++) {
                    double currentLat = modelLocation.get(count).getLatitude();
                    double currentLng = modelLocation.get(count).getLongitude();
                    if ((currentLat == latLng.latitude) && (currentLng == latLng.longitude)) {
                        TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
                        TextView textViewAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_address);
                        TextView textViewLocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_location);
                        final NetworkImageView imageViewUserImage = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_infoWindow);
                        textViewTitle.setText("" + modelLocation.get(count).getName());
                        textViewAddress.setText("" + modelLocation.get(count).getAddress());
                        textViewLocation.setText(currentLat + ", " + currentLng);

                        mImageLoader = VolleySingletonClass.getInstance(LocationActivity.this).getImageLoader();

                        String url = "My URL Of Image";
                        imageViewUserImage.setImageUrl(url, mImageLoader);
                        imageViewUserImage.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.ic_user_default);
                        imageViewUserImage.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.ic_user_default);
                    }
                }
                return view;
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, Activity2.class);             
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    static boolean isMarkerOnArray(List<MarkerOptions> listMarkerOptions, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        for (int count = 0; count < listMarkerOptions.size(); count++) {
            MarkerOptions current = listMarkerOptions.get(count);
            if ((current.getPosition().latitude == markerOptions.getPosition().latitude) && (current.getPosition().longitude == markerOptions.getPosition().longitude))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LocationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LocationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocationActivity.this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_FOR_ACCESS_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_FOR_ACCESS_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
                    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
                } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocationActivity.this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_FOR_ACCESS_LOCATION);
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void dropic_pinEffect(final Marker marker) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final long duration = 1000;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new BounceInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = Math.max(1 - interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration), 0);
                marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 1.0f + 7 * t);

                if (t > 0.0) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 15);
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {}

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getLocation();
        if (canGetLocation()) {
            double lat = getLatitude();
            double lng = getLongitude();

            MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            markerOptionsList = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        } else {
            showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    }
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        }
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, (LocationListener) this);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        double lati = 0;
        if (location != null) {
            lati = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return lati;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        double longi = 0;
        if (location != null) {
            longi = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longi;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

I searched on Google that why image is not display, So i got to know that i need to refresh info window adapter may be. Or is it Volley implementation issue?

Please suggest me **That my implementation is right or not** and what step should i perform to **Display Image in image view on window open**

Comment: have u logged the json to see if you actually get the image? or have you tried putting an image from your resources just to check if it's working

Comment: I applied image to the NetworkImageView in XML. so it is visible. I am getting the URL in log too..

Comment: maybe this is helpful.. http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-volley-imageloader-networkimageview-example/

Comment: have you found the solution?